# Why Django DateField doesn't accept empty values?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a model with a DateField field with blank = True and null = True.
It seems that is not possibile save an object with an empty value for the Datefield.

```
class ProjectTask(models.Model):
    actual_start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Then try with Python console:

```
p = ProjectTask.objects.all().last()
p.actual_start_date = ""
p.save()
```

The results is:

```
venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1273, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
```

I'm using Python 3.4, Django 1.9 and PostgreSQL.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It will show up, but `blank` means that the field is not required in a `ModelForm`. The null value is indeed `None`.

Answer (score 7):

Dates are not strings. If you want to pass a string, it needs to be converted to a date. Normally, your form would validate whether or not you had a valid date, but you've bypassed this by setting an empty string directly on the model.

If you don't want to set a value at all, then pass None.

Comment: It means change `p.actual_start_date = ""`  by `p.actual_start_date = None` .